# background image doesnt appear on ie

Tags: html, css

This works on firefox and chrome:

```
<div id="popup" style="display: block;">
        <div id="contentWrapper">

            <div id="popHeader">
                <span id="popupQuestion">The  nature.</span>
                <a id="popupYes" href="#"> </a>
                <a id="popupNo" href="/">Leave</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


#contentWrapper {
background-image: url("http://bestcamctory.com/images/warning/warning_bg.png");
height: 100%;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
}
```

But on ie the background image isnt shown. Why is that?

Comment: Are the child elements floated?

Comment: They are positioned absolutely

Comment: Note: IE8 and earlier do not support multiple background images on one element.The value "inherit" is not supported in IE7 and earlier. IE8 requires a !DOCTYPE. IE9 supports "inherit".
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

Comment: what ie version is the image not showing up? I see it in ie7 and ie8 http://jsfiddle.net/LyrwN/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your child elements are positioned absolutely, then `#contentWrapper` has collapsed because there's no elements within the normal flow of the document to tell it how tall to be.  A `height: 100%` is relative:  the element will only be as tall as its parent, which will only be as tall as its child elements by default (which are currently 0).

There are a few things you can try to work around this.

- Add a minimum height to `#contentWrapper` (try 1em to start with)
- Remove the absolute positioning from one or all of the child
  elements.

You could also try adding `height: 100%` to each of the ancestor elements.

Comment: adding height didnt help. removing absolute positioning is not an option. I dont know about adding height of 100% to each element.. it will screw things

Comment: Giving it pixel height and width didnt help too

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, you might need to define a size for the `contentWrapper` or the `popup` divs.